# Photoshop setting to achieve specific look

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

We had someone create a vinyl image of our dog years ago. She needed a high quality photo and then converted it to this vinyl image. Does anyone know what settings are used to achieve this look?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know it was done in Photoshop? That implies *some* research already.

Comment: No Photoshop filter included with the app will do this. Here is the closest thing that I found, but it is optimized for people not dogs. https://vanceai.com/photo-to-sketch/